# Loopback relationship nested $owner?

Tags: loopbackjs

in order to own the model, you need put "belongTo" in the relationship to User model in json file.

I have a case, Customer is belong to User and CustomerMedical is belong to customer. I am keep getting 401 code when I try to access CustomerMedical. I set CustomerMedical "belongTo" Customer. Is there anyway loopback is smart enough to know CustomerMedical also belongTo this user?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway loopback is smart enough to know CustomerMedical also belongTo this user?

Not unless you tell him also that CustomerMedical `belongsTo` user as well. You can add as many relations to a model as you want.

However, I don't know how you intend to use the `User` model, but your relation `Customer belongsTo User` is kind of weird, I have the feeling you may want to make Customer extend User (see [extending built-in models](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Extending+built-in+models))

Then should you just define CustomerMedical `belongsTo` Customer. (and use Customer for authentication as well).

Hope this helps.